# Access an element in a set?

Tags: c++, set

With a vector, I can do the following:

```
vector<int> myvec (4,100);
int first = myvec.at(0);
```

I have the following set:

```
set<int> myset;
myset.insert(100);
int setint = ????
```

How can I access the the element I inserted in the set?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
set<int>::iterator iter = myset.find(100);
if (iter != myset.end())
{
    int setint = *iter;
}
```

Comment: You should check `iter!=myset.end()` before dereferencing that iterator.

Comment: if you know you're looking for 100, why not just assign 100 to `setint`?

Comment: The equivalent to that in the `vector` case is `vecint = *find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 100);`

Answer (score 17):

You can't access set elements by index. You have to access the elements using an iterator.

```
set<int> myset;
myset.insert(100);
int setint = *myset.begin();
```

If the element you want is not the first one then advance the iterator to that element. You can look in a set to see if an element exists, using `set<>::find()`, or you can iterate over the set to see what elements are there.

Comment: The iterators and positions of elements are invalidated only if you erase items from the set.

Comment: Ah, sorry. inserting into a set doesn't invalidate old iterators, and erasing elements doesn't invalidate old iterators either (except of course for iterators pointing at the element removed).

Answer (score 7):

To access a particular index, you can use this :

```
int first = *next(myset.begin(),0);
int third = *next(myset.begin(),2);
```

The next function returns set iterator to that position.
Usually, this function is not used as its performance is linear. But if the set is small enough and there is a need to access some particular index, one can use this to avoid writing the manual iteration loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this approach :

```
 set<int>:: iterator it;
 for( it = s.begin(); it!=s.end(); ++it){
    int ans = *it;
    cout << ans << endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not important, one can also make a temporary copy to vector in order to access a specific element with a lazy one-liner.

```
int setint = vector<int>(myset.begin(), myset.end()).at(0);
```

Replace .at(0) with any index (you are sure of), or with .back() to get the last element.